# Retrieve int from activity to service does not work

Tags: java, android, service

I have the following to pass data from **`ACTIVITY`** to **`SERVICE`**

```
public static final String SOMKEY = "asdf";

private void startWatcherService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, servicefall.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(SOMKEY, value); //value is some changing int number
    serviceIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    this.startService(serviceIntent);

}
```

and this to retrieve the `int` using the `getInt()` in `onCreate` of the service

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    if (b != null) {
        b.getInt("asdf", 0);
        int score = b.getInt("asdf", 0);

        Log.i("retrieve", "retrieved value: " + score);
    }
```

Problem is the retrieved value is always 0 (default) even though in activity it's different. Am I doing something wrong retrieving the int using `getInt()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue!

Leaving it here just in case:

create **`OnStartCommand`** method:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int score = (int) intent.getExtras().get("asdf");

    Log.i("retrieve", "retrieved value: " + score);
    return score;
}
```

retrieve the int using `intent` parameter of the `onStartCommand` and `getExtras()` to gather what you've passed in the **`MainActivity`**. Then specify which key you want to retrieve.

if anybody has other ideas please feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

**Am I doing something wrong retrieving the int using getInt()?**

Yes you are doing wrong. You are calling `getInt()` method on the reference of that `bundle` that you are creating your own rather from the `bundle` you pass while creating activity. If you create new bundle object that will not have "asdf" key and by default int has **0**